# Use of semantic vectors

Tags: semantic-analysis

I want to use the *semanticvectors* API. I am completely new at this. I want to make a program which takes some documents and searches keywords and returns the documents which are conceptually similar to the search keywords. I want to know if there is any document from which I can get all the function and their functionality description and from which I can learn or if there is any example to do so.

I have checked 
https://code.google.com/p/semanticvectors/ 
and 
http://semanticvectors.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest-stable/index.html 
but couldn't understand anything. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: This seems way too general question.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Did you have a look to other APIs, tried examples ?

Comment: Do you want to search by keyword similarity in a set of documents?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do with SemanticVectors. Here is where you should start off with:

https://code.google.com/p/semanticvectors/wiki/InstallationInstructions

And for specific questions, it would be fruitful if you ask on project's forum itself:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/semanticvectors